# ScopedDbConnection throws "Couldn't connect to 127.0.0.1" sporadically, possible causes?

Tags: c++, mongodb

Actually, the exception message just says "Socket exception", but I went into the source code and saw "Couldn't connect to 127.0.0.1" message. Any suggestions?

To clarify: I have roughly 10 to 20 connections being made per second every second, and exceptions are being thrown like twice per minute on average with unpredictable intervals and density. I fail to see any pattern.

P. S. I'm getting this exception both on Windows and Linux. GDB and QtCreator suck on Linux, however, so I only investigated it on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 to 20 connections being made per second every second, you say?

You are almost certainly overflowing the "listen backlog" on the server.  When a POSIX server program wants to listen for incoming socket connections, it calls `listen()` with a `backlog` argument, which is often roughly 5-100 or so.  This sets the maximum number of incoming connections that the operating system will allow to be pending at the same time.  So you can have more than 100 connections, but you cannot have 100 (or maybe even 10) in flight at once on the server.  You can read about this here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/files/linuxjournal.com/linuxjournal/articles/023/2333/2333s2.html

And indeed from the MongoDB bug tracker it appears that they use a default of 5.  See here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2554 .  On the other hand, the actual code on GitHub shows a backlog argument of 128: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/5a2f4ceb93b44283500f1ed346898439ca33b137/util/net/listen.cpp#L138 , and I went back 2.5 years and it seems like it had it as 128 then too.  I'm not sure this is true, though--if it is, the Mongo people are not keeping their bug list up to date.

Comment: Thank you for the info, but there is always no more than 1 connection at any given moment. Connections are just being created and released quite fast, but the program is single-threaded and all connections are scoped.

Comment: Then I suggest you watch the connectivity using Wireshark and see if you can notice anything when it fails.

Comment: I think I understand the problem now. Looks like connections are not immediately closed, but rather put to an inactive state to be closed later. Considering that fact and a rate at which I create and destroy connection, I think I'm really running out of 128 connections. The question is now whether I can configure MongoDB server to close sockets immediately or not.

Comment: You can read about CLOSE_WAIT here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/janelewis/archive/2010/03/09/explaining-close-wait.aspx ... I suppose it's possible that some improvement could be made in the MongoDB server code with some careful use of the knowledge on that page (but then, maybe not--I haven't dug into it).

Comment: Found the problem! Turns out, I should call `done()` on a `ScopedDBConnection` after I'm finished with it's instance.